# Add event to Birthday calendar in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, addition

I wrote this code but it doesn't work, can you help me please? I'm stuck on it for last 2 hours.

```
- (IBAction)addBirthday:(id)sender {

    NSString *name = self.textField.text;
    NSDate *date = [self.datePicker date];

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@’s Birthday", name];

    event.startDate = date;
    event.endDate   = date;

    NSArray *calendars = [eventStore
                          calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

    NSLog(@"ARRAY: %@", [calendars objectAtIndex:0]);

    [event setCalendar: [calendars objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting??

Comment: No error, just not getting the event in calendar

Comment: http://pastebin.com/e0KRaRvR check out this code. This code works for me. I think there is problem in setting the calendar.

Comment: How can I set it to save the even in Birthday Calendar, not in the defaultCalendarForNewEvents?

Comment: @1337code http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/mobile/9781617290015/using-event-kit-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/ch16lev1sec2

Comment: You need to grand permission from user. refer my answer below,

Answer (score 1):

The birthdays calendar is likely read only

Comment: or whatever is at index 0 of your array

Comment: Yes, it's birthday calendar.
So I can't add event to it?

Comment: check calendar.isSubscribed. you cant add stuff to supscriptions AFAIK